# Line break inside curly braces

Tags: line-breaking

I know it's  rather a simple problem but i can't find solution to it. I want to put line break in this place:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l}
{\sc \Large
FIRST LINE HERE \\ SECOND LINE}
\par\vspace{0.2cm}\par
{\large
SOME TEXT
}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I get an error `Missing } inserted` and `Missing { inserted` and i suppose that's due to this line break in `\sc` and `\Large`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tabular` and `array` environments, each "cell" is its own (TeX) group. Hence,

```
{\sc \Large FIRST LINE HERE \\ 
SECOND LINE}
```

suffers from two defects:

- The first line starts with `{`, which starts a TeX group. But because the cell's scope ends at `\\`, TeX complains because it didn't find a group-ending token such as `}` *within that cell*.
- The second line ends with `}`, but TeX couldn't find a corresponding `{` token *within that cell*. Hence the second error message.

Oh, and don't use `\sc` in a LaTeX document; use `\scshape` instead.

Summing up, I think that what you really want is

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\scshape \Large FIRST LINE HERE \\ 
\scshape \Large SECOND LINE \\[2mm]
\large SOME TEXT
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```